# JQuery: How to extract an anchor from href

Tags: jquery

I am quite new to JQuery.

I would like to get the value of an anchor from a href with JQuery.

If I'd have the following example, how could i get the value "5" from the href with JQuery?

```
<a href="user/showUsers#5">User 5</a>
```

Thanks in advance

-James

Comment: what if you get two numbers instead of one, like 15, 16 etc. you want to get that whole number? or just the last character?

Comment: I actually would need all the values after the anchor #

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
var id = $('a').attr('href').split('#');
id = id[id.length - 1];
```

Comment: Note that fragment identifiers can contain subsequent `#` characters, which would break the above.

Answer (score 1):

These are called "Hash". Say your link had an id, you could get it like this:

```
document.getElementById("link").hash;
```

This would still give you the "#", but you can easily replace it:

```
document.getElementById("link").hash.replace("#","");
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the numbers given that the URL always follow the same structure try this out,

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var number = $("a").attr("href").match(/#([0-9]+)/)[1];
    alert(number);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you get the `href`, and then you get the part after the *first* `#`:

```
var href = $("selector_for_the_link").attr('href'),
    index = href.indexOf('#'),
    anchor = href.substring(index + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will bring all the anchor tags with some linked href value

```
$('a[href*="#"]').each(function(){
       if(this.href.split('#').length>1 && this.href.split('#')[1] != ""){                                                
           console.log(this.href.split('#')[1]);
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use this in several places or if you just want a cleaner code I suggest you take a look at this [URL parser](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser).

After you've installed it you just use it like this:

```
var anchor = $.url('http://yoursite.com/user/showUsers#5').attr('anchor');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 var id =  $(this).attr("href").split("#");
id = id[id.length - 1];
```

Answer (score -1):

Assumint that there will no more occurance of '#'.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function GetAnchorValue(CurrCtrl)
{
    var hrefText = $(CurrCtrl).attr("href");
    var RequiredValue;
    if(hrefText.indexOf("#") != -1)
    {
        RequiredValue = hrefText.split("#")[1];
    }
}
</script>
```

html tag will be

```
<a href="user/showUsers#5" onclick="return GetAnchorValue(this);">Test Anchor</a>
```